Error importing Tailwind CSS: "Module parse error: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)"
I'm facing an issue when trying to use Tailwind CSS in my React (or Next.js, if applicable) project. The app loads and works for a few seconds, but then displays the following error in the console:
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

@tailwind base;
|
| @tailwind components;

Context:
I'm using Webpack as a bundler (or Next.js, if applicable).
I've already installed Tailwind CSS and its dependencies according to the official documentation.
My tailwind.config.js file is configured correctly.
This is my postcss.config.js file:
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};

What I tried:
1.I verified that the dependencies are installed:
npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
2.I verified that postcss.config.js and tailwind.config.js are in the root directory.
**Additional detail:
**The app loads fine and works for a few seconds before throwing the error.
During those initial seconds, everything seems to be working, but then it stops responding and the error mentioned appears.
**Question:
**What could be causing the error to occur after a while and not at startup? Is it a problem with Webpack configuration, PostCSS, or something else? Thanks in advance!
